# Specify JRE for IntelliJ IDEA on Windows

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, java

How can I define which JRE IntelliJ IDEA should use to run on Windows?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the following [post](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-11368) it was specified that the paths look up sequence is the following:

1. IDEA_JDK env. variable
2. ./jre directory
3. registry
4. JDK_HOME environment variable

And indeed. Creating an IDEA_JDK environment variable did help.

Comment: Cannot help. Never used MacOS. Try specifying IDEA_JDK environment variable. I'm not sure about MacOS, but in Linux it can be done in the /etc/environment file.

Comment: Some tools also specify the JRE, e.g. Maven has a JRE setting under `Runner`, which can cause weird issues in case of a project with different modules that use different target environments.

Answer (score 4):

More actual information including JDK64 setup is [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827547-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under):

`<product>.exe` uses this JDK search sequence:

1. `IDEA_JDK` / `WEBIDE_JDK` / `PYCHARM_JDK` / `RUBYMINE_JDK` environment variable (depends on the product, `WEBIDE_JDK` applies to both WebStorm and PhpStorm)
2. `..\jre` directory
3. system `Registry`
4. `JDK_HOME` environment variable
5. `JAVA_HOME` environment variable

`idea64.exe` uses this JDK search sequence:

1. `IDEA_JDK_64` environment variable
2. `..\jre64` directory
3. system `Registry`
4. `JDK_HOME` environment variable
5. `JAVA_HOME` environment variable

It’s also possible to start the IDE with `<product>.bat` file located in the bin directory, it uses the following JDK search sequence:

1. `IDEA_JDK` / `WEBIDE_JDK` / `PYCHARM_JDK` / `RUBYMINE_JDK` environment variable (depends on the product)
2. `..\jre` directory
3. `JDK_HOME` environment variable
4. `JAVA_HOME` environment variable

Environment variable must point to the JDK installation home directory, for example:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_17
```

- `/create-i4j-log` command line switch can be used with the .exe to trace the JDK search sequence and find out why the specific JDK was chosen.
- The actual JDK version used by the IDE can be verified in `Help | About` dialog (open any project to access the menu).
- Define `IDEA_JDK` / `WEBIDE_JDK` / `PYCHARM_JDK` / `RUBYMINE_JDK` variable depending on the product to override the default version from `IDE_HOME\jre`.
- Use [Rapid Environment Editor](http://www.rapidee.com/en/download) to add/edit the variables, it will detect incorrect paths.